# How do I get Tan function to show undefined?

Tags: java, android, calculator, trigonometry

I am working on an android Calculator application which can calculate trigonometric functions.  I find that my Calculator shows:

```
Tan 90° = 1.633123935319537E16 instead of Tan 90° = undefined
Tan 270° = 5.443746451065124E15 instead of Tan 270° = undefined
```

I know these values actually mean `undefined` but these calculations might be a little confusing to the users. I am using Eclipse to make this app.

My question is "How do i get my Calculator to show the message `undefined` for Tan 90°, 270° and other values where Tan is infinity?".

This is my Code for Tan function:

```
ImageButton btnTan;
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnTan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTan);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    btnTan.setOnClickListener(this);

}

Double total = 0.0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTan) {
    if (txtDisplay.getText().equals("")) {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
    else {
        double total = 0.0;
        total = Math.round(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an `if`-statement.

Comment: Check on 90 or 270 before calculating. If 90 or 270 then calculating will not be performed.

Comment: You see the effect of rounding errors. 90 degrees, when converted to radians, are no longer exactly 90 degrees.

Comment: Which are those _"other values"_? Could you describe them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the degree value is 270, 90, or any other value where the tangent is `NaN`

```
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
    findViewById(R.id.btnTan).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTan) {
        double value = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
        if (value % 180 != 0 && value % 90 == 0) 
            txtDisplay.setText("undefined");
        else {
            value = Math.round(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(value)));
            txtDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VipanchithReddy Try it again, with above code you could do less wrong, although it was very hard to do it wrong in the first place. O well.

Comment: @VipanchithReddy Use above code, but what is the purpose of `total`? You don't have to use that value, I think.

Comment: @VipanchithReddy My method does exactly the same, but is more readable. You initialize total while you dont have to. You set the textview to empty while you dont have to. You set the new text as the value plus an empty string. Not necessary whatsoever. Use above code, it's much more easy to understand and read. furthermore, total is not an actual total, so the variable name is misguiding. Again, use above code, it works exactly the same as yours, but has less overhead and therefore, is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

Modifying the Code by changing

```
if (txtDisplay.getText().equals("")) {
    txtDisplay.setText("");
}
else {
    double total = 0.0;
    total = Math.round(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
```

to

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
if (value % 180 != 0 && value % 90 == 0) {
    txtDisplay.setText("undefined");
}
else if (value % 45 == 0) {
    double total = 0.0;
    total = Math.round(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
else {
    total = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())));
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
```

solved my problem.

So, my new Code is:

```
    ImageButton btnTan;
    TextView txtDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTan);
        txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

        btnTan.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    Double total = 0.0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTan) {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
            if (value % 180 != 0 && value % 90 == 0) {
                txtDisplay.setText("undefined");
            }
            else if (value % 45 == 0) {
                double total = 0.0;
                total = Math.round(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()))));
                txtDisplay.setText("");
                txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
            }
            else {
                total = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString())));
                txtDisplay.setText("");
                txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check if the value is 90° or 270°:

```
double value = Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText().toString()));
if (value == Math.abs(90) || value == Math.abs(270)) {
   txtDisplay.setText("undefined");
} else {
   total = Math.round(Math.tan(value));
   txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText().toString() + total);
}
```

Comment: and what about -90 and -270, and the infinitely many other values where tan is infinite?

Comment: @Henry I'm not a mathematician, I was just suggesting a technical solution without knowing the backgrounds. The question is incomplete in my eyes. This answer fits the question!

Comment: In the if-clause, use this: `(i % 180 != 0 && i % 90 == 0)` (where `i` is `value`). works for negatives as well.

Comment: Your code is actually checking if the angle is 90 radians or 270 radians; which isn't going to help with the problem at all.